# Angular element.width is not a function?

Tags: angularjs

Does `element.width()` not work anymore or am I wrong to assume that it gives you width of an element?

```js
angular.module('app', []).directive('app', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      console.log(element.width());
      // => Error: element.width is not a function
    },
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <app></app>
</div>
```

Comment: That's because it's using jqLite and not jQuery - it doesn't have a `width` function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

from angularjs angular.element's [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element):

> If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or "jqLite."

jqlite has a limited api, and it doesn't include .width() function